# Wrong Content-Length for response text with umlaut

Tags: java, spring, http, diacritics

There is a problem associated with umlaut.
I get  description on request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/description", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    private String getDescription() {        

        return "ärchik";
    }
```

on frontend response.responseText fails to score the last letter
response.responseText = "ärchi"

i found that the problem in the wrong Content-Length: 7
if  set Content-Length:8, then it will work and return full description "ärchik"

But i do not understand why 8?

```
"ärchik".getBytes("UTF-8").length = 7
```

**Response Headers**

Cache-Control:must-revalidate

Content-Length:7

Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8

Date:Mon, 14 Apr 2014 09:08:26 GMT

Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

Comment: Can you capture the raw bytes transferred? I wonder whether there might have been a conversion to NFD at some point, i.e. `ä` represented as *three* bytes `61 cc 88` (i.e. `'a'` followed by combining diaresis). But this is a pretty wild guess, and I don't have a Spring environment set up to test this.

Comment: It's my fault ((
I working out the filter `chain.doFilter(request, wrappedResponse);`
`byte[] bytes = wrappedResponse.getByteArray();` `String out = new String(bytes, utf8Charset);//7bytes`
`out = Normalizer.normalize(out , Normalizer.Form.NFD);//8bytes`

content-length is set before this
after normalization number of bytes was 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I'm turning the core of my comment into an answer, since it seems I was on the right track.*

The most likely reason for the string to be one byte longer than expected is that the `'ä'` got encoded as three bytes not two. This can happen if one uses not the precomposed codepoint U+00E4 (UTF-8: `c3 a4`) but instead the letter `'a'` (which is a simple ASCII letter at U+0061) followed by the [combining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) diaresis U+0308, together encoded as `61 cc 88`. There are several [normal forms for Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization#Normal_forms), and the longer encoding would usually be the result of conversion to NFD.

Looking at your own answer, it seems you did just that normalization, at a point where the content length already was determined from the un-normalized (or perhaps NFC-normalized) string.

Answer (score 2):

It's my fault (( I working out the filter

```
//set content-length = 7    
chain.doFilter(request, wrappedResponse); 
byte[] bytes = wrappedResponse.getByteArray(); 
String out = new String(bytes, utf8Charset);//7bytes 
out = Normalizer.normalize(out , Normalizer.Form.NFD);//8bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

spring/tomcat response is right.

```
  response.responseText is Ajax response Object?
```

I guess:  js file encoding not UTF-8 ; some function is not work for UTF-8  of javascript.